# Does Python have a .pdbinit file (similar to .gdbinit file)?

Tags: python, pdb

With `gdb` there is a `.gdbinit`[1] file that you can put lots of things that are important/necessary for more complex debugging sessions.

For example my recent Python debugging session required:

- numerous breakpoints
- numerous display expressions (similar to `watch` expressions in `gdb`)
- and I would like to have conditional breakpoints but they require lots of time and effort (if I had a `.pdbinit` file I would probably use them more often).

### Does Python have a `.pdbinit` file (similar to `.gdbinit` file)?

I would like to at the very least put a list of breakpoints into the `.pdbinit` file so that I do not have to type in a 2-10 or N breakpoints.

---

foot notes:

[1] for those of you not familiar with what is a .gdbinit file here is some information:

- [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gdbinit.5.html)
  I would like to at the very least put a list of breakpoints into the `.pdbinit` file so that I do not have to type in a 2-10 or N breakpoints.
- [more friendly tutorial](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Elearn/debugging/modules/gdb_init_file/)

Comment: I ended up writing my own conditional `breakpoints` function by a) writing a json file with a function/breakvarname/breakvalue.  b) loading that json file from a command line flag.  then, when I call ` if breakpoints("myfunc","customer","Smith"): breakpoint()` it will check if there is an entry `{"myfunc" : {"customer" : "Smith"}}`.  don't pass the json file as flag?  no effect.  different breakpoints?  pass in a different file.  could also work from an environment variable rather than a flag.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest file to `.gdbinit` is [`.pdbrc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands:%7E:text=If%20a%20file,had%20no%20effect.). This is where one can store aliases to make debugging more convenient. However, one can write arbitrary code in this file that can be used to extend the pdb debugger.

Most of the [tutorials](https://numbersmithy.com/debugging-python-using-pdb-and-pdbrc/#pdbrc_config) about this file cover aliases in detail, but you may be able to find a way to implement the requirements that you're seeking.